# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta entre "Con base en" y "En base a"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, selección-de-palabras, expresiones, sintaxis

Me he encontrado con que para mi, la forma mas natural de decirlo es `en base a`. Sin embargo, en ciertos escritos o en pláticas se me ha comentado que esa no es la forma correcta de decirlo, que tal vez antes sí lo era, pero ahora se dice `con base en`.
¿Es esto correcto?

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola! Efectivamente, de acuerdo con [el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=base) `con base en`, `a base de`, y `sobre la base de` son las forma correcta de la expresión. **Se desaconseja el uso de** `en base a`:

> [...] Es censurable la locución de sentido equivalente `en base a`, en la que las preposiciones `en` y `a` no están justificadas.